# ASP.NET Core 2.2 CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I'm having trouble to consume a ASP.NET Core 2.2 web api.

This javascript code below works well, I can get all clients fine

```js
fetch('https://10.20.0.20:8081/api/clients/list').then(data => { data.json().then(dt=>{console.log(dt)}) }).catch(error => { console.log(error)});
```

But this one doesn't work

```js
fetch('https://10.20.0.20:8081/api/clients/list',{ "headers": {"content-type": "application/json"}}).then(data => { data.json().then(dt=>{console.log(dt)}) }).catch(error => { console.log(error)});
```

Well... It is what I have in my ConfigureServices method from Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddCors(setup => setup.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials()));
```

My first line after Configure method from Startup.cs

```cs
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

**When I comment this line above both fetch stop working.**

I did this litle test just because I'm using angular to consume this API and I facing this same problem.

Error message:

> Access to fetch at 'https://10.20.0.20:8081/api/clients/Listar' from origin 'https://10.20.0.20:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

**I have same app/code in another IIS working. I guess that is something with IIS**

---

**EDIT -> 2020-05-16**

I did a middleware to check all requests methods with *context.Request.Method*. 
In my local machine I got GET and OPTIONS methods, but in this server I got only GET. I guess that the problem is with this server.

Comment: .WithExposedHeaders("content-type") - try adding this to CORS builder

Comment: .WithExposedHeaders("content-type") didn't work

Comment: in IIS , you need to add OPTIONS methods. by  default OPTIONS  is not available.

Comment: yeah... @user13422309 I figure it out last saturday, as I put on my *EDIT -> 2020-05-16*. Someone had put OPTIONS verb as false :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

someone had put OPTIONS as false in **Request Filtering** -> **HTTP Verbs** on IIS

Answer (score 0):

> It is what I have in my ConfigureServices method from Startup.cs
>
> `services.AddCors(setup => setup.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
>   builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials()));`

In your code, we can find that you configure both `AllowAnyOrigin` and `AllowCredentials` methods at the same time, which would cause the CORS service return an invalid CORS response.

Please modify your code to enable specific origins, like below.

```
services.AddCors(setup => 
    setup.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder => 
        builder.WithOrigins("https://10.20.0.20:8080")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials())
    );
```

> I have same app/code in another IIS working. I guess that is something with IIS

Please check if you enabled Windows Authentication for your IIS site, and you can try to install [IIS CORS module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-in-iis) and configured for your site.

Comment: It didn't work. I have same app/code in another IIS working. I guess that is something with IIS

Comment: Hi @ProgramadorDesenvolvedor, you can try to install IIS CORS module that provides IIS servers a way to correctly respond to the preflight request. For more information about CORS in IIS, please check my above update.